# *Highcharts* Get rid of the color in the percentage area chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a percentage area chart like this: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-stacked-percent and want to ask that are there any ways to get rid of the area's color ? so that we have only the lines and the white background ?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `line` series? See: http://jsfiddle.net/chpv2ref/

Comment: because I would like to display the percentage also, but anyway your solution is also very great, thank you so much

Comment: But it displays the percentage :) In Highcharts you can stack columns, areas or simple lines ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Historic and Estimated Worldwide Population Distribution by Region'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1750', '1800', '1850', '1900', '1950', '1999', '2050'],
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Percent'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:#ffffff">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b> ({point.y:,.0f} millions)<br/>',
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                stacking: 'percent',
                lineColor: '#ffffff',
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    lineColor: '#ffffff'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Asia',
            data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268]
        }, {
            name: 'Africa',
            data: [106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766]
        }, {
            name: 'Europe',
            data: [163, 203, 276, 408, 547, 729, 628]
        }, {
            name: 'America',
            data: [18, 31, 54, 156, 339, 818, 1201]
        }, {
            name: 'Oceania',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Ashwin, unfortunately the area' background colors are still there, I dont want to display them

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @Son. Were you able to solve it? If not, please share the code here.

Comment: hi @Ashwin, the problem was solved, here is the solution http://jsfiddle.net/c0o5v0gg/

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Historic and Estimated Worldwide Population Distribution by Region'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['1750', '1800', '1850', '1900', '1950', '1999', '2050'],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        title: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Percent'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b> ({point.y:,.0f} millions)<br/>',
        shared: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
                color: 'white',
            stacking: 'percent',
            lineColor: 'black',
            lineWidth: 1,
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: 'black'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Asia',
        data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268]
    }, {
        name: 'Africa',
        data: [106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766]
    }, {
        name: 'Europe',
        data: [163, 203, 276, 408, 547, 729, 628]
    }, {
        name: 'America',
        data: [18, 31, 54, 156, 339, 818, 1201]
    }, {
        name: 'Oceania',
        data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
    }]
});
```

});

the only problem is that line color will be same.

Comment: Hi robus, this is normal line chart, I would like a percent area chart but without the background's color

Comment: @Son could you elaborate on what you see as a difference between an area chart without colors and a line chart?

Comment: yes they look the same but in area chart they have percentage also which in line chart not

Answer (score -1):

You can use fillColor inside plotOptions --> area something like below.

```
plotOptions: {
    area: {
        fillColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
        stacking: 'percent',
        lineWidth: 1,
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: '#ffffff'
        }
    },
}
```

The working fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c0o5v0gg/).

For demonstration i have used the same example as high chart.

Comment: thanks J-D, one more question, can we change the color for seperate line, because now they all black

Comment: I just made a change for same. Revisit the fiddle or remove linecolor. It will automatically take the line color from series color.