# *Highcharts* Drawing Percent Line Chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a line chart like this :`

```
    series: [{
        data: [
            ['A', 29.9],
            ['B', 71.5],
            ['C', 106.4]
        ],
        name: 'l1'
    },
    {
        data: [
            ['A', 33.9],
            ['B', 22.5],
            ['C', 77.4]
        ],
        name: 'l2'
    },
    {
        data: [
            ['A', 55.9],
            ['B', 21.5],
            ['C', 134.4]
        ],
        name: 'l3'
    }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m1utpa41/

and I want to draw its line chart by percentage not by absolute value, how can I do that ?

Comment: I would like to draw the percent line for each of the series data, for example in the series l1, I want to draw line for 3 point A B C using percent value, not absolute value, and the percent value for point A means how many percentage that A takes in total of A B C of the series l1, and so on for series l2, l3,...

Comment: i do not understand you. maybe you draw an image with a sample.

Comment: @Nina: Son is referring to this Question he asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34200670/highcharts-get-rid-of-the-color-in-the-percentage-area-chart he wants a Chart similar to a stacked Area-Chart but without the area-color underneath. Which technically is a line-chart but that chart-type does not offer a stacking option iirc.

Comment: yes true, I would like to draw like the percentage area chart but without the stack

Comment: You need to pre-process your data, and output the percent values that you want to plot, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Set [`stacking`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<line>.stacking) to `percent` and optionally you could set [`valueSuffix`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.valueSuffix) for `tooltip`.

```
...
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    stacking: 'percent'
  }
},
tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: '%'
},
...
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1utpa41/3/

There is also an example in [stacking API reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<line>.stacking) - [Line with "percent" stacking demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-stacking-percent-line/)

**Edit:**

However, if you want to get a series that will have each data point set as percentage value of summarized data of the series, then there is no default option that would allow this feature, but you could just process you data.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/oxja7u7k/

[Related topic on Highcharts forum.](http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/highcharts-drawing-percentage-line-chart-t34501/)

Comment: thanks for your solution, it works for me, but because I have datetime x-axis and when I use keys:  keys: ['name', 'y', 'realVal'], the my datetime at the xaxis will be come Jan.1970 and when I get rid of the key, it shows the correct datetime at xaxis but then I can not call point.realVal at the tooltips anymore, how can I fix it ?

Comment: @Son In your question there was no such information. You could add `'x'` to `keys` and points, and set `xAxis` `type` to `datetime`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/oxja7u7k/1/